# Python microsoft graph API - /callback error

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

In my Django web application, I need to **enable SSO** - single tenant - Internal to the organization.

Based on ref tutorial: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python) I was able to copy-paste required code snippets in views.py, urls.py.

I also created an **oauth_settings.yml** file-

```
app_id: {app id}
app_secret: {app secret}
redirect: "http://localhost:8000/callback"
scopes:
    - user.read
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"
```

Yet every time after I submit the O365 credentials, I am facing the same /callback error :-

[image]

I have identified the issue to be in 'auth_flow' variable which holds entire flow dict. data which is reflected earlier, **but fails to be saved in the request.session**.

Please guide what exactly may be the issue at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured this redirect url in Azure?

Comment: Yes redirect uri is set as: http://localhost:8000/callback in Azure AD portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, when we were browsing to http://127.0.0.1:8000 instead of http://localhost:8000, we got the error. Because the browser does not store session and set cookie when using IP address. So please use  http://localhost:8000. to access project when you develop the project on your local machine. For more details, please refer to the [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-pythondjangoapp/issues/43#issuecomment-760211058)

use IP adreee
[image]

use localhost
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct key to extract the 'timeZone' is missing in the function `def store_user()`.

Go to the file `auth_helper.py` and replace the function store_user() with the following:

```
def store_user(request, user):
  try:
    request.session['user'] = {
      'is_authenticated': True,
      'name': user['displayName'],
      'email': user['mail'] if (user['mail'] != None) else user['userPrincipalName'],
      'timeZone': user['mailboxSettings']['automaticRepliesSetting']['scheduledStartDateTime']['timeZone'] if (user['mailboxSettings']['automaticRepliesSetting']['scheduledStartDateTime']['timeZone'] != None) else 'UTC'
    }
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```